# Sony bravia screen resolution problem when using Docky

Tags: 10.04, resolution, screen, docky

This is what it looks like:

[image]

When the laptop (MSI u100) starts up it takes up all available space on the TV screen. About a second after logging in the black bar at the bottom appears.

The strange thing is that as you can see the menus can be visible over it, also the dock (Docky app), and any fullscreen application (not maximised, but fullscreen).

So what would be the problem here?

The source of the problem is the Docky Application. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be a scaling thing with the background image.  What size is the background and what is the screen resolution?

Comment: no it's not the background image. If you notice there's an icon being cut off at the bottom left corner. Also, when it starts up it seems to be fine. The problem appears about a second after start up

Comment: According to your edit, the source of the problem is Docky. I have had Docky cause a similar problem on an ancient Dell desktop I have that did not have 3D or compositing working...do you have 3D/compositing working on your laptop? Docky requires this to display properly.

Comment: In Preferences > Appearance > Visual Effects I selected the second option (Normal) and all seems to be ok now, Docky did sent a notification that it needs compositing to work but up until now it worked properly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*(OP Solved problem)*

> In Preferences > Appearance > Visual Effects I selected the second option (Normal) and all seems to be ok now, Docky did sent a notification that it needs compositing to work but up until now it worked properly. Many thanks.